# cannot mount vfat partition after running efibootmgr

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, parted

I have created partition on my USB disk with `parted`

```
parted /dev/sdb
 mklabel gpt
 mkpart boot fat32 0% 1024MB
 set 1 esp on
 set 1 boot on
```

then I formatted the partition

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb1
```

mounted and copied my files

finally, I ran:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sdb --part 1 --loader /EFI/BOOT/syslinux.efi --label "Syslinux" --unicode
```

after that, I am no longer able to mount the partition:

```
# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp/
mount: /mnt/tmp: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
   dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

but the disk works as bootable UEFI disk, so the partition is still there. I just cannot mount it !!!

I am doing this on Debian 12

here is strace: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQzO6_EQ

## UPDATE:

this is strange:

i just found out, I can mount the partition if I first map it with `kpartx`:

```
kpartx -a -p -kpartx- -s -v /dev/sdb
mount /dev/mapper/sdb-kpartx-1 /mnt/tmp/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you need to have following additional kernel modules loaded to mount EFI partitiin:

```
efi_pstore
efivarfs
```

Comment: Those modules refer to the UEFI NVRAM variable store, which gets mounted to `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` and is stored on the motherboard's BIOS settings memory, not on any disk.

Answer (score 0):

Does your kernel not have the `CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION` option enabled (titled "EFI GUID partition support", which means GPT partition tables)?

That would mean the kernel will not have the ability to parse the GPT partition table, and would need user-space tools such as `kpartx` to build mappings for individual partitions.

`kpartx` brings its own code for parsing MBR and GPT partition tables, so it will work even if the kernel does not understand GPT.

Since a GPT partition table includes a *protective MBR*, a GPT-unaware kernel will typically detect a single MBR primary partition of type 0xee on any GPT-partitioned disk. That partition will cover the whole disk, or the 2 TB or so a MBR partition table can handle. It's purpose is just to indicate "this disk is in use by something you don't know about" to any MBR-only OSs and partitioning tools.